# How to specify the position of main object without redrawing all figure?

Tags: tikz-trees

I have plotted the original graph (left) and I need to draw a tree (right). In the origial graph the node v1 is the main circle. It was used to draw all objects (circle and lines).
My problem is the position of v1 node because all object placed relative it.

[image]

My attemp is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 60pt,
C/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=10pt}
]
\node[C] (v1) {$v_1$};
\node[C, below of=v1] (v8) {$v_8$};
\node[C, right of=v8] (v9) {$v_9$};
\node[C, below of=v8, xshift=-1cm, yshift=1cm] (v7) {$v_7$};
\node[C, below of=v8] (v6) {$v_6$};
\node[C, left  of=v6, xshift=-1cm] (v2) {$v_2$};
\node[C, right of=v6] (v5) {$v_5$};
\node[C, below of=v6] (v3) {$v_3$};
\node[C, right of =v3, xshift=1cm] (v4) {$v_4$}; 
\draw
(v1) --node[above]{1} (v9)
(v9) --node[left]{1} (v5)
(v1) --node[above]{10} (v2)
(v9) --node[above]{0.5} (v8)
(v8) --node[pos = 0.9, right]{0.5} (v7)
(v7) --node[pos = 0.9, left]{1} (v6)
(v2) --node[above]{1} (v6)
(v6) --node[above]{1} (v5)
(v2) --node[above]{8} (v3)
(v5) --node[above]{2} (v3)
(v5) --node[left]{2} (v4)
(v3) --node[above]{9} (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 60pt,
C/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=10pt}
]
\node[C] (v1) {$v_1$}; % 
\node[C, below of=v1, xshift=2.1cm, yshift=2cm] (v9) {$v_9$};
\node[C, below of=v1] (v6) {$v_6$};
\node[C, left  of=v6, xshift=-1cm] (v2) {$v_2$};
\node[C, right of=v6] (v5) {$v_5$};
\node[C, below of=v6] (v3) {$v_3$};
\node[C, right of =v3, xshift=1cm] (v4) {$v_4$}; 
\draw
(v1) --node[above]{1} (v9)
(v9) --node[left]{1} (v5)
(v2) --node[above]{1} (v6)
(v6) --node[above]{1} (v5)
(v5) --node[above]{2} (v3)
(v5) --node[left]{2} (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Question.** Is it possible to specify the position of main object without redrawing all figure?

Comment: Remember to accept the answers you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with an empty `(v1)` node (or `\coordinate (v1);` ) and at the very end, you replace the node, where you really want it.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=60pt,
C/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=10pt}
]
\node (v1) {};
\node[C, right of=v1] (v9) {$v_9$};
\node[C, below of=v1] (v6) {$v_6$};
\node[C, left  of=v6, xshift=-1cm] (v2) {$v_2$};
\node[C, right of=v6] (v5) {$v_5$};
\node[C, below of=v6] (v3) {$v_3$};
\node[C, right of =v3, xshift=1cm] (v4) {$v_4$}; 
\node[C, above left of=v9] (v1) {$v_1$};
\draw
(v1) --node[above]{1} (v9)
(v9) --node[left]{1} (v5)
(v2) --node[above]{1} (v6)
(v6) --node[above]{1} (v5)
(v5) --node[above]{2} (v3)
(v5) --node[left]{2} (v4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Connected graph]